# Mi IDE no detecta bs4

Tags: python, windows, cmd, python-import, idle

Lo que pasa es que cuando descargue con pip el modulo "BeautifulSoup" y después el modulo "bs4" puse todo el código de prueba en el CMD (Símbolo del sistema) funciona perfectamente el importe

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> #Nice
>>>
>>>
>>>
```

Pero el problema llega cuando quiero ponerlo en el IDLE y lo ejecuto

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

¿Por que no funciona en mi IDLE?

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda. Gracias por su atención.

Comment: Hola, intenta corriendo `python -m pip3 install beautifulsoup4` si eso no funciona intenta corriendo el `pip` en la terminal de idle

Comment: Si funciona en el CMD pero no en el idle, es síntoma de que tienes al menos dos versiones de python diferentes instaladas en tu sistema. La terminal estaría usando una (en la que instalastte bs4), mientras el idle usaría la otra (en la que bs4 no está instalado). Puedes asegurarte de que el idle esté usando la misma versión que la terminal si lo lanzas desde la terminal, escribiendo "idle". O si eso no funciona, desde la terminal escribiendo `python -m idlelib.PyShell`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda